# Construct a triangle given an angle, the length of internal angle bisector for that angle, and the incircle radius.

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, triangles, geometric-construction

I need to write a proof for the following problem. Let theta be an arbitrary angle and suppose the length of the internal angle bisector to that angle and the length of the inradius are given. Perform the construction, discuss the number of possible triangles and give the conditions for each.

I started by constructing the angle given, and bisecting it and making the length of the bisector the length given. From there, I dropped perpendiculars to the sides of the vertex from the bisector, since the center of the incircle will lie somewhere on the angle bisector. Is this correct? Or how can I go about this? I also am not sure about the last portion of the questions regarding the conditions.

Comment: Your posting would benefit from a diagram.  For help managing an image, see the Images section, at the bottom of 
[this article](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and see also 
[this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33909/recommendation-enhance-the-mathse-html-markdown-help-article-re-images).

Comment: If you draw a line, parallel to one of the sides of the angle, within a distance from the side equal to the inradius, it will intersect the bisector at the incenter. Can you take over from here? I mean after you have your angle and bisector with given length in place.

Comment: @GReyes that makes perfect sense. I can complete the construction now from there. Thank you for your response! The only question that remains is what conditions do these 3 measurements need to satisfy in order to be able to construct a triangle? I know the angle bisector needs to be longer than the incircle radius, but other than that, I am not sure what other conditions need to be met.

Comment: From the end point of the bisector you should be able to draw a line, tangent to the incircle. You have three cases there: no solution, one solution or two solutions.

Comment: @GReyes, thank you so much for your help.